# Networking is in AsyncTask and NetworkOnMainThreadException error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

I want to grab some data from remote database and I have some networking in my AsyncTask subclass of my activity, but when I try to load my program it shows NetworkOnMainThreadException.

here is my code:

```
public class MyMapLocationActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
private static String url_product_details = "http://myurl.com/readfromdb";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
private static final String TAG_POINT = "point";

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    ReadLocations Read = new ReadLocations();
    Read.execute();
}

//And my networking AsyncTask:

class ReadLocations extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
       Log.d("debug", "START DOINBACKGROUND");


       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               // Check for success tag
               int success;
               try {

                   // Building Parameters
                   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "16"));

                   // getting product details by making HTTP request
                   // Note that product details url will use GET request
                   Log.d("debug", "before http request");

                   JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                           url_product_details, "POST", params);
                   Log.d("debug", "after http request");

                   // json success tag
                   success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                   if (success == 1) {
                       // successfully received product details
                       JSONArray productObj = json
                               .getJSONArray(TAG_POINT); // JSON Array

                       // get first product object from JSON Array
                       JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                   }else{
                       // product with pid not found
                   }
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });

        return null; 
    }



  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String text) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
   Log.d("debug", "ONPOSTEXECUTE");

    }
```

The LogCat shows "before http request" but doesn't show my "after http request" check.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Network code is on **MainUiThread** of Application not in worker thread...

remove

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
```

from `doInBackground()`

and put the **WebRequest** code only in `doInBackground()` of AsyncTask..

**Update:**

Actually your **AsyncTask** implementation for `doInBackground()` is wrong. As  `doInBackground()` runs in worker thread for lengthy and network related operation. And you are trying to run **MainUiThread** form it using `runOnUiThread()` which is not in rule.. If you want to make any UI related work do it in `onPostExecute()`, `onPreExecute()` and other methods of ASyncTask.

Comment: How could i miss that? Thanks : )

Comment: Thats absolutely right. You should consider accepting that answer.

Comment: I did : ) It can't be done too fast, here are some time limits.

Answer (score 1):

Have a go at this code :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
   Log.d("debug", "START DOINBACKGROUND");

           // Check for success tag
           int success;
           try {

               // Building Parameters
               List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "16"));

               // getting product details by making HTTP request
               // Note that product details url will use GET request
               Log.d("debug", "before http request");

               JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       url_product_details, "POST", params);
               Log.d("debug", "after http request");

               // json success tag
               success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

               if (success == 1) {
                   // successfully received product details
                   JSONArray productObj = json
                           .getJSONArray(TAG_POINT); // JSON Array

                   // get first product object from JSON Array
                   JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

               }else{
                   // product with pid not found
               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return null; 
}
```

The problem with your code is that you are running the network functions on the Main UI thread only, by using this :  `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...}`.

The doInBackground() automatically runs on a separate background non-ui thread and you do not need to create a thread explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're running network code on your UI thread... Your `doInBackground` explicitly runs the network code on the UI thread.